# How to add (successful) URL connections to file

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of URLs and I need to test if they exist (about 8000-9000, each on its own line).

What I'm trying to do is automate the process of sending a request to each URL, and if it is a genuine URL, append it to the file, and if there is an error or failure in connecting to the URL, not add it to the file, this way I have a file with only genuine URLs.

I'm trying to do this in Python using the python-requests library, but my code doesn't work. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
import requests

with open("/origin/file.txt") as urls:
    lines = urls.readlines()

for i in lines:
    r = requests.get(i)
    try:
        r
    except NameError:
        print "Unsuccessful in connecting, discarding URL..."
    else:
        print "Successful connection! Adding URL to file..."
        with open("/destination/file.txt", "a") as genuine
            print i + "\n"
    del r

urls.close
genuine.close
```

Comment: what is the variable `f`?

Comment: What are you expecting from `try: r; except ...`?  And while you are opening `genuine`, you never write anything to it.  Maybe, you could also elaborate a bit on what “doesn't work”.

Comment: Sorry about that - edited out variable f. It was an unedited mistake from my copy-pasting the wrong file over. Everything else is as my original code.

@5gon12eder - What isn't working is that when I run it, it throws an exception when it encounters a request that is unsuccessful. How can I get Python requests to iterate over an unsuccessful request without failing? As for the file...after it opens the file it prints i to it followed by a newline.

Comment: As a first aid measure, remove the `close()`s at the end.  The file is implicitly closed at the end of a `with` clause.  (The second of which is missing a `:` at the end.)  Since you already seem to know how to `catch` and handle exceptions, can't you simply apply that to the exception that `requests.get(i)` might throw?

Comment: after looking at the documentation really quick... i would test `r.status_code`to see how the request went (200 or not or whatever, you decide what counts as valid).

Comment: @5gon12eder The `try: r; except` behavior is intended to only write to a file if the request is successful. If the request is successful, the variable r will be defined. If the request is not successful, r will remain undefined.

Comment: you need to put `try: r = requests.get(..)`... it already executes the get before you hit the try, so you wouldn't be catching errors at that point.

Comment: @1111IIIIII111111IIII1 No, if in `r = requests.get(i)` the `requests.get(i)` returns (no matter what), `r` will always be assigned to.  And if it does not return, you'll never make it to the next line.

Comment: also... you could open your output file at the top, not each time you hit a valid url.  but you should write each time you hit a valid url to record it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weird part about what you're doing is that you're not wrapping the part that's most likely to error out `requests.get(someurl)` in a `try/except` block. Instead, you are wrapping the response object (which, if it exists, means that the `requests.get` was some kind of successful):

```
for i in lines:
    r = requests.get(i)
    try:
        r
    except NameError:
        print "Unsuccessful in connecting, discarding URL..."
    else:
        print "Successful connection! Adding URL to file..."
        with open("/destination/file.txt", "a") as genuine
            print i + "\n"
    del r
```

I would suggest something little more something like this:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ConnectionError, MissingSchema

...
    for url in lines:
        try:
            resp = requests.get(url)
            if resp.ok:
                # now you can add the url to the file
        except (Timeout, ConnectionError, MissingSchema):
            pass
```

Comment: And it is working! Thanks! I will upvote once I have enough reputation ^_^